# Change encoding of txt file

Tags: bash, encoding, echo

When I write :

```
file file1.txt
```

I have this output : **Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CR line terminators**

Then if I write :

```
file file2.txt
```

I have :  **ASCII text**

file2.txt is created by making :

```
echo $var > "file2.txt"
```

I would like file2.txt have the same encoding than file1.txt. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `iconv` to convert the encoding of the file:

```
iconv -f ascii -t utf16 file2.txt > another.txt
```

`another.txt` should then have the desired encoding.

You could also try this:

```
echo $var | iconv -f ascii -t utf16 > "file2.txt"
```

Answer (score 8):

Use iconv:

```
echo "$var" | iconv --from-code=utf-8 --to-code=utf-16le --output=file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

When converting your file, you should be sure it contains a byte-order mark. Even though [the standard says a byte-order-mark isn't recommended for UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/9636), [there can be legitimate confusions between UTF-8 and ASCII without a byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223976/9636).

Additionally, specifying `UTF-16BE` or `UTF-16LE` [doesn't prepend a byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924403/9636), so I first convert to `UTF-16`, which uses a platform-dependent endianness. Then, I use `file` to determine the actual endianness and the convert from that to `UTF-16LE`.

Finally, when you create a file using `bash`, the file receives `bash`'s `locale charmap` encoding, so that's what you need to map from.

(I uppercase all my encodings because when you list all of `iconv`'s supported encodings with `iconv -l` they are all uppercase.)

```
BASH_ENCODING="$( locale charmap | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] )"
echo $var | iconv -f "$BASH_ENCODING" -t UTF-16 > UTF-16-UNKNOWN-ENDIANNESS-FILE
FILE_ENCODING="$( file --brief --mime-encoding UTF-16-UNKNOWN-ENDIANNESS-FILE )"
iconv -f "$FILE_ENCODING" -t UTF-16LE UTF-16-UNKNOWN-ENDIANNESS-FILE > file2.txt
```

Comment: If you downvoted this, would you explain why?